# How do I create a new package within the src folder? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, src

I apologize that this question is something that is easy, but I am having trouble creating new packages within my src folder. If someone could help me out that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 12):

Right-click over the `java/` directory and choose New > Package from the context menu. Type in the package name, and click OK.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much.

Comment: can i do this keyboard shortcut ?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei: There doesn't appear to be one by default, though it looks like you might be able to add one via Settings > Keymap.

Comment: wow! thx it was easy to find it. 
just alt+insert+d. NICE! thx a lot.